# Move to next Edit text

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

i have customEditText

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/five_margin"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout"
   >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sub_heading"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hind_text_col0r"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/active_text_col0r"
      />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and using it As follow

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.paisa.main.base.ui.widget.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/custom_edt_investor_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

        <com.paisa.main.base.ui.widget.CustomEditText
        android:id="@+id/custom_edt_nominee_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

how can i move investor name to nominee name edit text via soft input keyboard
i had use imeoption next bt it didn't work its hide the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you :- make this for all TextView ...

```
custom_edt_investor_name.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
          if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
               (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
          {
                // Perform action on Enter key press
                custom_edt_investor_name.clearFocus();
                custom_edt_nominee_name.requestFocus();
                return true;
          }
          return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: i use that bt it did work , and i have a lot use of this custom view in my app .

Comment: its work on my case. OK let me try more for your solution .

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:nextFocusDown` param to specify which field you'd like to get focus when the user hits the enter key.

**Example** :

```
android:inputType="text"
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/..."
```

Comment: its working on myside. may be because you are using customEditText @V.R.Ranga

Comment: android:nextFocusDown is not applicable on your com.paisa.main.base.ui.widget.CustomEditText but is usefull for android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout @V.R.Ranga

Comment: i thing in CustomEditText this android:nextFocusDown wont be applicable so might have to use simple or other edittext @V.R.Ranga